# inet_ntoa problem

Tags: c, sockets

I am declaring following variables

```
unsigned long   dstAddr;
unsigned long   gateWay;
unsigned long   mask;
```

These variables contains ipaddresses in network byte order. So when I am trying to print the dot notation using inet_ntoa function for mask variable sometimes it is printing strange values. The below code is in a while loop .. which loops for n times.

```
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\t",inet_ntoa(dstAddr),inet_ntoa(gateWay),inet_ntoa(mask));

  192.168.122.0         0.0.0.0    0.255.255.255
```

but it should be

```
  192.168.122.0         0.0.0.0    255.255.255.0
```

I printed the HEX values of the variables and it shows ..

```
007aa8c0    00000000      ffffff00
```

So is this because of inet_ntoa ??

Actually I am trying to get the values of the declared variables from 254 routing table in kernel via NETLINKS. I guess I should still use inet_ntoa function to convert the value into dot notation .. ??

Comment: Just a warning, inet_ntoa is deprecated - you should be using inet_ntop() or inet_pton() instead.

Comment: inet_ntop() and inet_pton() are also deprecated as they don't support IPv6 scope identifiers.  You should be using getaddrinfo() and getnameinfo() if you want IPv6 support.

Comment: @codingfreak, whatever is setting your mask is wrong. The value should be 00ffffff as per my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing that makes sense is that your assumption regarding all the addresses being in network byte order is incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

Well, given that it works for your non-mask values (including the first which also has the high bit set), I'd be looking at what `mask` actually contains.

What is it when you print it out as a normal unsigned long? My bet is that `mask` is actually not the correct value:

```
printf ("%08x\t%08x\t%08x\n", dstAddr, gateWay, mask);
```

(assuming you have four-byte longs).

For example, this little program (compiled under Cygwin):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    unsigned long dstAddr, gateWay, mask;
    dstAddr = 0x007aa8c0;
    gateWay = 0x00000000;
    mask    = 0x00ffffff;

    printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s\n",
        inet_ntoa (dstAddr),
        inet_ntoa (gateWay),
        inet_ntoa (mask));

    printf("%-15s ",  inet_ntoa (dstAddr));
    printf("%-15s ",  inet_ntoa (gateWay));
    printf("%-15s\n", inet_ntoa (mask));

    printf ("%08x%8s%08x%8s%08x\n",
        dstAddr, "",
        gateWay, "",
        mask);

    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
192.168.122.0   192.168.122.0   192.168.122.0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0
007aa8c0        00000000        00ffffff
```

Note that I had to separate my calls to `inet_ntoa` as it appears to use a static buffer. When I was doing it all within a single `printf`, it overwrote the contents of that buffer before any of them were printed, hence I only got the last one processed. I don't *think* that's happening in your case since you're getting different values.

Comment: Then your mask has been set incorrectly as I surmised. It should be 00ffffff, *not* ffffff00. You need to find out where that's being set and fix it. This is *not* a problem with inet_ntoa.

Comment: I guess hex value for 255.255.255.0 is ffffff00 ?? check with the following tool - http://www.kloth.net/services/iplocate.php

Comment: You have to be aware of the byte order for both the network and your architecture (little or big-endian). Plug 192.168.122.0 into that same tool and you get C0A87A00 which is also the wrong order. On little-endian, the value 0x01020304 is stored in memory as 04,03,02,01.

Comment: A small doubt, I am actually getting the values from kernel via netlink sockets .. so still big and little endian comes into picture ??

Comment: Now you've moved beyond my areas of expertise, @codingfreak. All I can say is, that from empirical evidence, the mask is wrong. I've never used netlinks interface before.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem with you.
Use inet_ntop() and inet_pton() if you need it other way around. Do not use inet_ntoa(), inet_aton() and similar as they are deprecated and don't support ipv6.
see link: [convert Ip address int to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328070/how-to-convert-string-to-ip-address-and-vice-versa)