# How to convert string to IP address and vice versa

Tags: c++, string, struct, ip-address, in-addr

how can I convert a string ipAddress (struct in_addr) and vice versa?
and how do I turn in unsigned long ipAddress?
thanks

Comment: **WSAAddressToString** and **WSAStringToAddress**

Answer (score 195, accepted):

Use `inet_ntop()` and `inet_pton()` if you need it other way around. Do not use `inet_ntoa(), inet_aton()` and similar as they are deprecated and don't support ipv6.

Here is a nice [guide](https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) with quite a few examples.

```
// IPv4 demo of inet_ntop() and inet_pton()

struct sockaddr_in sa;
char str[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

// store this IP address in sa:
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.0.2.33", &(sa.sin_addr));

// now get it back and print it
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa.sin_addr), str, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

printf("%s\n", str); // prints "192.0.2.33"
```

Comment: What should I do to use them under Windows?
What should I include?

Comment: If using winsock then InetNtop and InetPton on windows vista and later. Header file Ws2tcpip.h . A tip is to look at examples on msdn.

Comment: WSAAddressToString (ntop) and WSAStringToAddress (pton) in Winsock2.h. I would suggest an upgrade to at least vista, and to ask you that next time you specify what platform you are developing when asking questions :)

Comment: @Milan Thanks! Everywhere says to use the inet prefix functions, but only 1 of them is included in Winsock2.

Comment: There is also `RtlIpv(4|6)AddressToString/Ex()` and `RtlIpv(4|6)StringToAddress/Ex()` functions

Comment: This link is not available any more

Comment: What do "p" and "n" mean in these functions? If I know the meanings I can probably remember them better.

Comment: What about IPv6?

Comment: @QiFan The "n" stands for "network", and the "p" for "(text) presentation".

Comment: @Milan: Hey, do you know if there is a function to achieve exactly the same, but that allows for a name as src-string instead of the IP address in dotted decimal form? I want to give a name that can be resolved by my DNS server instead

Comment: This doesn't work. `localhost` resolves to arbitrary IPs that have nothing to do with my actual IP.

Comment: I am wondering why all languages consider ip as a string than a 32 bit integer?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if I understood the question properly.

Anyway, are you looking for this:

```
std::string ip ="192.168.1.54";
std::stringstream s(ip);
int a,b,c,d; //to store the 4 ints
char ch; //to temporarily store the '.'
s >> a >> ch >> b >> ch >> c >> ch >> d;
std::cout << a << "  " << b << "  " << c << "  "<< d;
```

[Output:](http://ideone.com/xPi4n)

```
192  168  1  54
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to convert string to DWORD and back with this code:

```
char strAddr[] = "127.0.0.1"
DWORD ip = inet_addr(strAddr); // ip contains 16777343 [0x0100007f in hex]

struct in_addr paddr;
paddr.S_un.S_addr = ip;

char *strAdd2 = inet_ntoa(paddr); // strAdd2 contains the same string as strAdd
```

I am working in a maintenance project of old MFC code, so converting deprecated functions calls is not applicable.

Answer (score 4):

[`inet_ntoa()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738564.aspx) converts a `in_addr` to string:

> The inet_ntoa function converts an
>   (Ipv4) Internet network address into
>   an ASCII string in Internet standard
>   dotted-decimal format.

[`inet_addr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738563.aspx) does the reverse job

> The inet_addr function converts a
>   string containing an IPv4
>   dotted-decimal address into a proper
>   address for the IN_ADDR structure

PS this the first result googling "in_addr to string"!

Comment: Those functions are deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: @Milan OK. Though the OP uses in_addr struct that deal with ipv4

Comment: What should I do to use them under Windows?
What should I include?

Comment: The answer is in the function's documentation, (follow the link): include Winsock2.h.

Answer (score 3):

To convert string to in-addr:

```
in_addr maskAddr;
inet_aton(netMaskStr, &maskAddr);
```

To convert in_addr to string:

```
char saddr[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &inaddr, saddr, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
```

Answer (score 3):

This example shows how to convert from string to ip, and viceversa:

```
struct sockaddr_in sa;
char ip_saver[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];

// store this IP address in sa:
inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.0.1.10", &(sa.sin_addr));

// now get it back 
sprintf(ip_saver, "%s", sa.sin_addr));

// prints "192.0.2.10"
printf("%s\n", ip_saver);
```

Comment: adding the header would have been nice too

Answer (score 0):

The third `inet_pton` parameter is a pointer to an `in_addr` structure.  After a successful `inet_pton` call, the `in_addr` structure will be populated with the address information.  The structure's `S_addr` field contains the IP address in network byte order (reverse order).

```
Example : 

#include <arpa/inet.h>
uint32_t NodeIpAddress::getIPv4AddressInteger(std::string IPv4Address) {
    int result;
    uint32_t IPv4Identifier = 0;
    struct in_addr addr;
    // store this IP address in sa:
    result = inet_pton(AF_INET, IPv4Address.c_str(), &(addr));
    if (result == -1) {         
gpLogFile->Write(LOGPREFIX, LogFile::LOGLEVEL_ERROR, _T("Failed to convert IP %hs to IPv4 Address. Due to invalid family of %d. WSA Error of %d"), IPv4Address.c_str(), AF_INET, result);
    }
    else if (result == 0) {
        gpLogFile->Write(LOGPREFIX, LogFile::LOGLEVEL_ERROR, _T("Failed to convert IP %hs to IPv4"), IPv4Address.c_str());
    }
    else {
        IPv4Identifier = ntohl(*((uint32_t *)&(addr)));
    }
    return IPv4Identifier;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's easy-to-use, thread-safe c++ functions to convert uint32_t native-endian to string, and string to native-endian uint32_t:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h> // inet_ntop & inet_pton
#include <string.h> // strerror_r
#include <arpa/inet.h> // ntohl & htonl
using namespace std; // im lazy

string ipv4_int_to_string(uint32_t in, bool *const success = nullptr)
{
    string ret(INET_ADDRSTRLEN, '\0');
    in = htonl(in);
    const bool _success = (NULL != inet_ntop(AF_INET, &in, &ret[0], ret.size()));
    if (success)
    {
        *success = _success;
    }
    if (_success)
    {
        ret.pop_back(); // remove null-terminator required by inet_ntop
    }
    else if (!success)
    {
        char buf[200] = {0};
        strerror_r(errno, buf, sizeof(buf));
        throw std::runtime_error(string("error converting ipv4 int to string ") + to_string(errno) + string(": ") + string(buf));
    }
    return ret;
}
// return is native-endian
// when an error occurs: if success ptr is given, it's set to false, otherwise a std::runtime_error is thrown.
uint32_t ipv4_string_to_int(const string &in, bool *const success = nullptr)
{
    uint32_t ret;
    const bool _success = (1 == inet_pton(AF_INET, in.c_str(), &ret));
    ret = ntohl(ret);
    if (success)
    {
        *success = _success;
    }
    else if (!_success)
    {
        char buf[200] = {0};
        strerror_r(errno, buf, sizeof(buf));
        throw std::runtime_error(string("error converting ipv4 string to int ") + to_string(errno) + string(": ") + string(buf));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

fair warning, as of writing, they're un-tested. but these functions are exactly what i was looking for when i came to this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Hexadecimal IP Address to String IP

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint32_t ip = 0x0AA40001;
    string ip_str="";
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            temp += ip & 15;
            ip = ip >> 4;
        }
        else
        {
            stringstream ss;
            temp += (ip & 15) * 16;
            ip = ip >> 4;
            ss << temp;
            ip_str = ss.str()+"." + ip_str;
            temp = 0;
        }
    }
    ip_str.pop_back();
    cout << ip_str;
}
```

Output:10.164.0.1

Answer (score 0):

summarize :

```
inet_ntoa((in_addr)recvAddrStruct.sin_addr)
```

step by step :

```
SOCKET m_viSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);

struct sockaddr_in recvAddrStruct;
recvAddrStruct.sin_family = AF_INET;
recvAddrStruct.sin_port = htons((unsigned short)port);
recvAddrStruct.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");  // inet_addr()


  // get back in string

printf("IP : %s",    inet_ntoa((in_addr)recvAddrStruct.sin_addr));   // inet_ntoa ()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use two functions
defined in `winsock2.h` on windows, in `netdb.h` on Linux

•[`WSAStringToAddressA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsastringtoaddressa)(For converting a  string to an address)

•[`WSAAddressToStringA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsaaddresstostringa)(For converting an address to a string)

Best thing about these two functions is that they work for every address family

### WSAStringToAddressA

This function takes to five arguments

•A pointer of array or array of `char` containing your address

•Address family of your address(Only used if argument 3 is `NULL`)

•`WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` structure providing information about your protocol, leave null if you want to use argument 2

•Pointer to the structure of `sockaddr` in which the result address has to be stored

•Pointer of the object  of type `DWORD` in which the result length of your address has to be stored

WSAAddressToStringA

This function also takes five arguments

•Pointer to the structure of `sockaddr` that has to be translated

•Byte length of your address

•Structure of `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` giving information about the address's protocol. Use `NULL` to make the function use address family of `sockaddr` structure in argument 1

•Array of `char` in which the address in the form of string has to be stored

•Length of the string form of your address in bytes

### Example

```cpp
#define _WIN32_INNT 0x601

#include <iostream>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <ws2spi.h>

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsd;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsd);
    char *addr="127.0.0.1";
    sockaddr h;
    int i;
    WSAStringToAddressA(addr,AF_INET,NULL,&h,(DWORD*)&i);
    char addr2[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int i2;
    WSAAddressToStringA(&h,i,NULL,addr,(DWORD*)&i2);
    std::cout<<addr2;
}
```

### Result

`127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell:

```
[System.Net.IPAddress]::Parse("10.128.1.50").Address
[System.Net.IPAddress]::new(838959114).IPAddressToString
```