# How to make duplicate ip headers in C?

Tags: c++, c, network-programming

i'm trying to make a .pcap file after receiving RTP pcakets.
While trying to frame a fake ip header i'm not able to assign ip address directly
I know i need to use the structure as below .

```
char src[]="192.168.134.12";
/* Prepare fake IP header */
hdrp->iphdr.ip_v = 4;
hdrp->iphdr.ip_hl = sizeof(hdrp->iphdr) >> 2;
hdrp->iphdr.ip_len = htons(sizeof(hdrp->iphdr) + sizeof(hdrp->udphdr) + sizeof(rtp->rawdata +   AST_FRIENDLY_OFFSET));
**hdrp->iphdr.ip_src = sstosin(&src);//error line
hdrp->iphdr.ip_dst = sstosin(&src);//error line**
hdrp->iphdr.ip_p = htons(16001);
hdrp->iphdr.ip_id = htons(i++);
hdrp->iphdr.ip_ttl = 127;
hdrp->iphdr.ip_sum = rtpp_in_cksum(&(hdrp->iphdr), sizeof(hdrp->iphdr));

/* Prepare fake UDP header */
**hdrp->udphdr.uh_sport = sstosin(&src);//error line**
hdrp->udphdr.uh_dport = htons(6666);
hdrp->udphdr.uh_ulen = htons(sizeof(hdrp->udphdr) + sizeof(rtp->rawdata + AST_FRIENDLY_OFFSET));

 This is the structure
 struct in_addr{
unsigned long s_addr;}
```

**How can i assign ip address to "unsigned long s_addr"??**

how do i hard code or assign my ip address to these error lines??

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert string to ipaddress](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328070/convert-string-to-ipaddress)

Answer (score 0):

You cant assign an array. 
try memset instead:

something like that:

```
memcpy ( destAddr, srcAddr, sizeof(data) );
```

Comment: How can i assign ip address to "unsigned long s_addr"??