# How to assign an addr_in struct to an array of uint8_t

Tags: c++, sockets, getaddrinfo

Consider the following code snippet:

```
uint8_t addr[4];
inet_pton(AF_INET, args.gtp_bind_addr.c_str(), addr);
```

The function `inet_pton()` takes an IP-address in dotted decimal form (`args.gtp_bind_addr.c_str()`), converts it into an `in_addr struct` and copies this struct to `addr`.

Now, assume I am given a `sockaddr_in struct`, let's call it `help`. And I want to write the `addr_in` entry of help into my `addr` array. Would this be possible simply by the following command: 
`addr[0] = help->sin_addr` ?

This seems a little wrong as I am now assigning the `sin_addr` just to `addr[0]`, but I want it to fill the entire `addr` array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string to IP address and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328070/how-to-convert-string-to-ip-address-and-vice-versa)

Comment: assigning a `uint32_t` to a `uint8_t` will simply cause the `uint32_t` to be truncated.

Answer (score 1):

`help.sin_addr` is a `struct in_addr`, a class type that wraps a single 32-bit integer.

A `struct in_addr` is assignable (from another `struct in_addr`). It's not a `uint8_t`, though (how could it be), so your proposed assignment is never going to work. If you'd tried writing such a program, you would have been told this by your compiler.

So, no, it doesn't make much sense. The problem is that you chose to use an array with `inet_pton`, when there was no need to. All you needed to do was provide another `struct in_addr` to fill:

```
struct in_addr addr;
inet_pton(AF_INET, args.gtp_bind_addr.c_str(), static_cast<void*>(&addr));
```

Now the assignment you want to perform is both valid and completely intuitive.

But, wait! Why bother with the middle-man, then? Just read directly into your target:

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, args.gtp_bind_addr.c_str(), static_cast<void*>(&help->sin_addr));
```

Job done.

Comment: I think OP means to assign an `in_addr` to an array of `uint8_t` like this: `uint8_t addr[] = { 192, 168, 1, 1 };`. In that case another answer already points that the way to go with it is using `memcpy`.

Answer (score 1):

It happens that `struct in_addr` has exactly 4 bytes, the same size of your `uint8_t` array. You can copy the contents of the `in_addr` (which just contains a `uint32_t`) using `memcpy`:

```
memcpy((void *)addr, (void*)&help.sin_addr.s_addr, sizeof help.sin_addr.s_addr);
```