# Weird behavior of inet_ntoa

Tags: libpcap, inet

I was playing with libpcap and found a strange thing.

One part of the output is:
"From: src_addr, To: dst_addr"

If I print with one statement, i.e.
printf("From: %s, To: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip_hdr->ip_src), inet_ntoa(ip_hdr->ip_dst));
The printed dst_addr is exactly the same as the printed src_addr. However, when I set a break point at this line and use gdb to examine the values stored in ip_src and ip_dst, they are different.

If written in two statements, i.e.
printf("From: %s, ", inet_ntoa(ip_hdr->ip_src));
printf("To: %s\n", inet_ntoa(ip_hdr->ip_dst));
Then the problem disappeared and the src_addr and dst_addr in the output are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same and it is because the function uses a static buffer. More explanation can be found in [inet_ntoa problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513550/inet-ntoa-problem) (look on the third post).